# Summernote gem on active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, summernote

I'm trying to use summernode gem on activeadmin form 
I have this code in my post.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :user_id, :title, :body, :featured_image

  controller do
    def find_resource
      scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      scoped_collection.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Blog Post' do
      f.input :title
      f.input :featured_image
      f.input :body, input_html: { 'data-provider' => "summernote"}
      f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: current_admin_user.id}
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

but it is not working.

Comment: did you tried this `f.input :body, as: :summernote`

Comment: I tried it but it also gives me error "wrong number of arguments (given 6, expected 4..5)"